# Rails: Shoulda Matchers and validates username on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec-rails, shoulda

Model Validation:

```
validates :username, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_.-@]+\Z/i, message: "must contain only letters, numbers or _*-@" }, on: :update, :if => :username_changed?
```

Rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User, "references" do
  it { should have_and_belong_to_many(:roles) }
  it { should belong_to(:account_type) }
  it { should belong_to(:primary_sport).class_name("Sport") }
  it { should belong_to(:school) }
  it { should belong_to(:city) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
  it { should allow_value("test@test.com").for(:email) }
  it { should_not allow_value("test.com").for(:email) }

  describe "validation of username", focus: true do
    before(:each) do
      @user = User.new(email: Faker::Internet.email, password: "password", password_confirmation: "password", username: "test123", agreed_to_age_requirements: true)
    end

    it "should be valid" do
      @user.save
      @user.should be_valid
    end

    it "should not be valid with incorrect characters in username" do
      @user.username = "test@@@!!!"
      @user.should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    agreed_to_age_requirements true
    username Faker::Internet.user_name
  end 
end
```

I am basically just trying to test against the custom validation for the uniqueness of and with the specified format of the username

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Using Rspec, how would I write a test that tested against this: `validates :username, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_.-@]+\Z/i, message: "must contain only letters, numbers or _*-@" }, on: :update, :if => :username_changed?`

Comment: @Vimsha - I updated my question with my latest attempt on writing a test